# В чём отличие FixedUpdate и Update? Когда они вызываются?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-faq

Я начинаю изучать *Unity3d* и одна из вещей, которая мне не ясна - это разница между методами `Update()` и `FixedUpdate()`.

В своих проектах я использую метод `Update()` и всё работает хорошо. В чём отличие метода `FixedUpdate()` и обычного `Update()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Быстрое описание: `Update` вызывается каждый кадр, а `FixedUpdate` с фиксированной частотой независимо от FPS. При этом частоту можно изменить в настройках *Unity*.

Его частота зависит от того, насколько быстро компьютер способен отображать изображения. На более медленном компьютере `Update` вызывается реже, чем на более быстром. Если вы выполняете расчеты на основе времени, вы можете нормализовать их, используя `Time.deltaTime`, который скажет сколько времени прошло с момента последнего вызова `Update`. Обычно его используют для выполнения задач, связанных с отображением (например, обновление элемента пользовательского интерфейса)

`FixedUpdate` вызывается с фиксированной частотой независимо от FPS. При этом частоту можно изменить в настройках *Unity*. Вызывается фиксировано независимо от того, как часто изображение обновляется.
Обычно используют для выполнения задач, связанных с игровым процессом (например, обновление физики).

---

Чуть подробнее:

Я сначала напишу псевдокод и добавлю диаграммы ниже, которые, возможно, помогут понять что к чему.

В приведенном ниже (полностью вымышленном) коде сначала выполняется соответствующее количество физических шагов, чтобы «догнать» текущее время (и на каждом шаге вызывается `FixedUpdate()` для каждого объекта, который его реализует). Затем отрисовывается графика для кадра, за которым уже следует `Update()` для каждого объекта, который ее реализует.

```
var physicsTimeSimulated = 0;
var lastUpdateTime = 0;    
 
 while (Unity is Running) {
     while (physicsTimeSimulated < Time.time) {
         Engine.ExecutePhysicsStep();
         Engine.FixedUpdate(); // <-- отправляется всем объектам
         physicsTimeSimulated += physicsTimeStep;
     }
 
     deltaTime = Time.time - lastUpdateTime;
     Engine.RenderFrame();
     Engine.Update(); // <-- отправляется всем объектам
     lastUpdateTime = CurrentTime;
 
     // повтор...
 }
```

Если игра работает с низкой частотой кадров, между каждым видимым рендером кадра будет множество обновлений физики. И наоборот, если игра работает с очень высокой частотой кадров, между рендерингом некоторых кадров может вообще не быть шагов физики, потому что время, прошедшее с момента последнего рендеринга кадра, еще не превысило период времени одного физического шага.

У Юнити можно настроить количество обновлений физики в секунду. По-умолчанию это "0,02", т.е. это примерно 50 обновлений физики в секунду (каждый шаг физики имитирует движение, которое происходит в течение двух сотых секунды).

Итак, для начала простая диаграмма, где показан период в одну десятую секунды. Точки, разделяющие линию, обозначают сотые доли секунды. А "F", чтобы показать, равные деления вызова метода `FixedUpdate`

```
0                                                0.1 seconds
|                                                 |
.____.____.____.____.____.____.____.____.____.____.___ 
F         F         F         F         F         F
```

Теперь, если бы наша игра работала хорошо и быстро со скоростью 100 кадров в секунду, у нас было бы два рендера кадра для каждого шага физики и, следовательно, два вызова наших функций `Update` для каждого вызова наших функций `FixedUpdate`

*(«F» обозначает вызов `FixedUpdate`, «U» - `Update`)*

```
0                                                0.1
|                                                 |
.____.____.____.____.____.____.____.____.____.____.___ 
F         F         F         F         F         F
U    U    U    U    U    U    U    U    U    U    U
```

Если наша игра работает медленнее, скажем, со скоростью 30 кадров в секунду (и, следовательно, 30 вызовов всех функций `Update` в секунду), это будет означать, что на самом деле у нас иногда бывает более одного физического шага между рендерингом каждого кадра. В случае 30 кадров в секунду результатом будет то, что иногда между кадрами выполняются два физических шага, а иногда один, который будет выглядеть примерно так, в течение первых 10 долей секунды:

```
0                                                0.1
|                                                 |
.____.____.____.____.____.____.____.____.____.____.___ 
F         F         F         F         F         F
 U                U               U                U
```

Таким образом, в большинстве обычных обстоятельств вы всегда будете получать желаемое и постоянное количество физических шагов в кадре, и вместе с ними будут чередоваться обновления визуального кадра с максимально возможной скоростью.

По этой причине `FixedUpdate` следует использовать когда используются силы (Force) к объекту, крутящих моментов или других функций, связанных с физикой, потому что вы знаете, что он будет выполняться точно синхронно с самим физическим движком.

В то время как `Update` может отличаться от физического движка, быстрее или медленнее, в зависимости от того, какую нагрузку графика накладывает на движок рендеринга на текущий момент времени (что при использовании данного метода для физики дало бы не постоянную и не корректную работу)

Исключением было бы то, что если бы ваша сцена оказывала такую ​​нагрузку на физический движок, что она приближалась бы к точке, когда становится невозможным выполнить необходимое количество физических шагов по времени, чтобы идти в ногу с «реальным временем». Это означает, что вашу игру стало невозможно моделировать в реальном времени, и в этом случае вам нужно серьезно подумать о переработке вашей игры! Это может произойти, если у вас есть большое количество сложных объектов (например, коллайдеров сетки твердого тела), которые сгруппированы вместе, поэтому на каждом шаге возникает множество столкновений «многие ко многим».

---

<sub>Частичный перевод: http://answers.unity.com/answers/11002/view.html с дополнениями, вставками, размышлениями....</sub>