# Проблема со столкновениями Unity3d. Передвижение по типу "Tomb Of The Mask". Объект перестаёт двигаться

Tags: c#, unity3d, обработка-столкновений

С помощью туториала написал код, позволяющий управлять персонажем. При нажатии на клавишу объект начинает двигаться в определённом направлении до момента, пока он не встретит препятствие.
Но есть проблема, иногда, когда объект передвигается, он может "застрять" в стене, после чего перестаёт двигаться и как-либо отвечать на нажатие клавиш. Нигде в интернете я не нашёл решения данной проблемы.

Скрипт, отвечающий за передвижение:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

enum Direction
{
    North,
    South,
    East, 
    West
}

[SerializeField]
float speed;

[SerializeField]
LayerMask obstacleMask;

Direction MovingDir;

Rigidbody rb;
bool movingHorizontally, canCheck;

void Start ()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update ()
{
    if (movingHorizontally)
        canCheck = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.left, .6f, obstacleMask) || Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.right, .6f, obstacleMask);
    else
        canCheck = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.forward, .6f, obstacleMask) || Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.back, .6f, obstacleMask);

    if (canCheck)
    {
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") != 0)
        {
            rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionZ;
            rb.freezeRotation = true;

            movingHorizontally = true;

            if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0)
            {
                MovingDir = Direction.East;
            }
            else
            {
                MovingDir = Direction.West;
            }
        }
        
        else if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") != 0)
        {
            rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX;
            rb.freezeRotation = true;

            movingHorizontally = false;
            
            if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0)
            {
                MovingDir = Direction.North;
            }
            else
            {
                MovingDir = Direction.South;
            }
        }
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    switch(MovingDir)
    {
        case Direction.North:
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            break;
        case Direction.South:
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, -speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            break;
        case Direction.East:
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, 0, 0);
            break;
        case Direction.West:
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(-speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, 0, 0);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

[image: Объект игрока]
[image: Столкновение со стеной]

Comment: Зочем физика... Тут без физики можно...

Answer (score 0):

В общих словах, проблема у вас заключается в том, что движение вы делаете физическое, а вот обработку коллизий - в `Update()`. Все расчеты, связанные с физикой нужно выполнять в `FixedUpdate()`. В противном случае, возможны рассинхронизации в ваших вычислениях и ожиданиях.

Если чуть конкретней, то проблемы из разряда "застрял в стене" происходят как раз по причине того, что движение происходит по физике, а коллизии считаются вне физике. `Update()` вызывается с частотой обновления кадров (FPS) в вашей игре, тогда как `FixedUpdate()` фиксированное количество раз в секунду. И этим двум интервалам обновления никак не обязательно быть синхронизированными между собой, в частности, FPS - совсем не константная величина. Как раз из-за этого вы можете получить информацию о коллизии уже в тот момент, когда она перестала быть актуальна, и объект прошел сквозь стену.

Для большего понимания почитайте, пожалуйста, вопрос про [разницу между Update и FixedUpdate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1272449/%D0%92-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-fixedupdate-%D0%B8-update-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F).

Comment: Перенёс свой код из метода Update() в метод FixedUpdate(), однако это не помогло; проблема, что куб перестаёт двигаться после столкновения с другим объектом, осталась

Comment: @АртёмГаргел теперь надо проверить, что объект не застревает внутри стены. Тут у вас предположение на том, что половина грани куба это 0.6, проверьте, что это действительно так. Кроме того, вы еще точку для коллизии рассчитываете от transform, который также не синхронен с физикой и его положение обновляется по fps. Дальше вам нужно в отдадчик и искать баг. Хотя я бы физическое движение убрал в пользу перемещения transform.position в update(). Да и юнити сами пишут, что изменение rb.velocity редко когда применяется

Comment: Я не использую перемещение при помощи transform.position потому, что мне необходимо, чтобы объект двигался с довольно большой скоростью, а при использовании transform.position объект проходит сквозь стены. Половина грани куба у меня 0.5, а 0.6 я использую, чтобы проверить, может ли пользователь изменить направление движения куба. По идее, я рассчитываю не коллизии, а возможность изменить направление (ведь куб должен двигаться в одном направлении, пока не встретит препятствие; при его движении направление изменить нельзя). Прошу прощения, если ошибаюсь в чём-то или если веду себя слишком глупо

Comment: Извиняюсь, но я никак не могу найти, где совершил ошибку